# Blazor WASM client has become unstable in Large Spa

Tags: blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have a fairly large Blazor client WASM application.  Things were going great and I hit a wall.

After last week I seem to hit a wall.  Things that happen are:

- Some breakpoints don't work
- Debug build the server dies, which may be the cause of the above.
- Console.WriteLines don't work in chrome but seem to in Edge
- Unexpected Exceptions are thrown on will used services.

I think there is some other weirdness, but don't remember off the top of my head.  I am starting to think Blazor WASM isn't ready for prime time.

Has anyone else seen this?

How much data memory to Blazor have access to?

How large can the Blazor WASM code be?

Comment: How large are we talking component wise/cascading parameters/nested components/`StateHasChanged()`? I have a feature-rich Blazor WASM that performs very well.

Comment: I would say about 5 non-page components and 30-40 page components.  Then I fetch about 70 meg of data using REST.  Data was being stored in a SortedList or just a list.  Each "table" has 2 to 4 sorted lists for at most 20 lists.  At some point, weird things started to happen.  Data would be missing, etc.  I switch to Blazor server and the app worked and fetching the data was 12-20 faster.  I expected a small bump by going directly to the DB instead client->web api->db.  I tried changing everything to an unsorted list on the client then using lambda, with no joy.

Comment: Have you considered using gRPC for the data retrieval/streaming? Super duper fast bud! ;) Also, that app is not large at all. I have a similar size app working great but I am also utilizing browser storage for caching. The app is for Stock Market Analytics so there is a significant amount of data being downloaded per session.

Comment: I am just using in-memory list for caching.  I also didn't think it was a large app, but I still don't know what the limits are.  I haven't considered gRPC yet.  I still have a lot to do before I wrap up this alpha test.  I could believe I screwed up something, but it is strange that as soon as I went to server-sde everything started working again.  I am also loading all of SyncFusion Blazor packages.  It just feels like memory corruption.

Comment: "I am also loading all of SyncFusion Blazor packages." there might be your problem! Package bloat has always been the drawback to .NET. Why not write the controls yourself? I highly doubt you utilize the entire package.

Comment: Time constraints on writing my own controls, but the new SyncFusion does allow only installing the components I need, which I didn't do.  I am bad.

Comment: Hahaha! It happens :)